# Switching between Azure Mobile Services vs my own implementation. Will UIDs change?

Tags: security, azure, oauth, openid, oauth2

I'm looking at Azure Mobile Services, particularly the Authentication part (which I believe relies exclusively on OAUTH 1 or 2).

I want to make sure that my application isn't tightly coupled to the service and I can bring authentication back in-house using either of the following methods:

1. I use a version of Azure Mobile Services built for 2012 R2 (which may include support for AMS + OAUTH)
2. I use a local DLL such as .NET Open OAuth to handle the authentication.

My theory is that UIDs are portable between all three scenarios (the third being Azure Mobile Services itself), because I manually would be typing in the same secret into each provider.

My second gut reaction is that any Windows Live IDs will not have the same URL and aren't portable in these scenarios (based on my Azure ACS and LiveID experience).  However since I've noticed OAuth support in .NET OpenID I think I could be mistaken.

**Question**

Could someone more well versed in authentication, and Microsoft products let me know if authentication can be "moved" to and from Azure Mobile Services if needed?

The main contention point I believe will be differing user IDs after the switch which would mean that after migration, users will loose their previous history, etc. in my application.